# Create Numpy matrix using linspace and ones

Tags: python, numpy

With Numpy, I thought I could create a matrix this way

```
 z = np.array( [np.linspace(0, 1, 2), np.ones((1, 2)), np.ones((1, 2))] )
```

which, however, gives me:

```
array([array([ 0.,  1.]), array([[ 1.,  1.]]), array([[ 1.,  1.]])], dtype=object)
```

then checking its shape:

```
>>> z.shape
(3,)
```

The column dimension does not exist. 
So I think I got an array with three array objects.

How can I have the 3 x 2 matrix using linespace() and ones() here?

Comment: It was the mixed dimensions ( `(2,)` and `(1,2)`) that produced the 1d object array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the inputs are 1-dimensional, you could use `numpy.array`:

```
np.array([np.linspace(0, 1, 2), np.ones((2,)), np.ones((2,))])
```

yields

```
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
```

---

Note that `np.ones((1,2))` has a 2-dimensional shape `(1,2)`, while `np.linspace(0, 1, 2)` has a 1-dimensional shape `(2,)`. To create the desired result with `np.array`, the arrays need to have compatible shapes -- in this case, that means using the 1-dimensional array `np.ones(2,)` instead of `np.ones((1,2))`.

---

If you must use `np.ones((1,2))`, then you could instead make `np.linspace(0, 1, 2)` 2-dimensional as well, and then use [`numpy.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html):

```
np.vstack([np.linspace(0, 1, 2)[np.newaxis, :], np.ones((1,2,)), np.ones((1,2,))])
```

yields

```
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: With compatible dimensions you don't even need `vstack`.  Plain `np.array` works: `np.array([np.linspace(0,1,2),np.ones((2,)),np.ones((2,))])`

Comment: @hpaulj: Yes, I missed the easiest solution. Thanks for the improvement.